# Create multiple instances of an image with text from csv file

Tags: adobe-photoshop, batch-processing, photoshop-scripting, script, microsoft-excel

I am looking for a way to create a personalized birthday card. I have already created the image and would like to add the names of the recipients from an XLS or CSV file. I want to create about 300 instances of the same image and save them separately. Can I do this with Photoshop or some other utility?

Answer (score 2):

This is exactly what Indesign Data merge feature is made for.
Have a look here: https://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/using/data-merge.html

Comment: OK Stefanos, Data merge is great! The question is: does your text have special effects that can only be done with Photoshop?